# DoCmd.GoToRecord adding 1 to target record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form embedded in a NavigationSubform two layers deep in an access 2010 database.  I am using the onclick event of an uneditable textbox in the continuous form to change the source object property of the current navigation subform to a detail form that should be cued up to the specific record indicated by the textbox on which the user clicked.

The problem is that access sends the user to +1 the record id (addr_id) rather than to the desired addr_id.  This produces wrong data most of the time.  It also produces an error message when the user clicks on the highest current addr_id.  And oddly enough access sends the user to the correct addr_id if and only if the addr_id = 1.

Here is the code for the onclick event which is causing trouble:

```
Private Sub AddressID_Click()
    Dim addr_id As Long
    addr_id = Me.AddressID
    Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "AddressDetails"
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, addr_id
End Sub
```

I tested a hack edit of this to "fix" the problem as follows:

```
Private Sub AddressID_Click()
    Dim addr_id As Long
    Dim new_addr_id As Long
    addr_id = Me.AddressID
    Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "AddressDetails"
    If addr_id = 1 Then
        new_addr_id = addr_id
    Else
        new_addr_id = addr_id - 1
    End If
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, new_addr_id
End Sub
```

But my "fix" seems like a complete hack because there clearly must be a better solution.  Can anyone show me how to fix this code so that I do not have to add the if-else logic to handle this funny re-routing that access is doing?

Comment: I bet it is something to do with changing the form source.  I know when I needed similar user behavior in the past, rather than resource the subform, I opened a new form that pointed to the original subform's active record in its sourcing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to see your table to be sure but the issue might be GoToRecord offsets the number specified from the beginning of the recordset. This means that if you have an address id of 51 it will take you to record 51 in theory.

The problem with using this method is that if you delete any `AddressID` then 51 will not be the record you want because it is taking you to the 51st record regardless of `AddressID`.

For Example I add 100 Records to Addresses with IDs 1-100 then I delete the first 99 of them and I am left with `AddressID` 100 if I use this command I will receive the standard "You can't go to the specified record." becuase I am telling access to go to a record that does not exist.

Please check you table to make sure that all the `AddressID` fields are exactly in order and let me know. Generally I would not recommend this as a method of navigation.

Is `AddressID` a auto-increment number in access? Are you guaranteeing that an address will never be deleted?

Try this

```
'expression.SearchForRecord(ObjectType, ObjectName, Record, WhereCondition)
Docmd.SearchForRecord acForm,"NavigationSubform",,"AddressID=" & addr_id
```

This will actually search the record set for the WHERE condition specified and Go To that record. Note this goes to the First record it finds which should not be a problem since you are using an ID.

Using Filter

```
With Me.NavigationSubForm.Form
    .Filter = "AddressID=" & addr_id
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

This will only show the results with that Address ID in the subform

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  I tried your DoCmd.SearchForRecord syntax, but it is giving me runtime error 2489, the object NavigationSubform is not open.  Of course, I also tried the name of the form and also Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.Form and others, but I still get runtime error 2489.  Any suggestions for how to reference the navigation subform, given the correct information about how to reference its sourceobject in my original posting above?

Comment: IF you do not need navigation ability in the subform you can use filter. I do this a decent amount instead of directly linking subforms in access. I have added the code to my answer

Comment: This works now, so I am going to mark yours as the answer.  I did have to replace your Me with the actual Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.Form because Me refers to a textbox in this context.  But the code works after I made that small change.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay wasn't sure how you had things structured glad I could help